# Issue getting JS Google Maps API to display map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps

When I search an address the map will never generate! Im going crazy trying to figure out why.

The element is there, the loader function is getting called, I have tried to take out side of the loader function & call the api from index.html to no avail.

Im stumped!

I would like it so when I search the address, the map pops up along with the rest of the content showing the location. However, only the property images from my API show up. Nothing else. The div element named "map" shows up but with no content what so ever.

```
  <div class="about">
    <div id="topInput">
      <div id="searchWrapper">
        <vue-google-autocomplete id="map" country="us" classname="form-control" placeholder="Type an address..."
          v-on:placechanged="getAddressData">
        </vue-google-autocomplete>
        <button @click="getRealestateData" class="searchButton">
          Go
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="topImages">
      <property-images v-if="getPropertyData" :propImages="getPropertyData.propertyData.property_detail.photos" />
      <div id="map"></div>
      <!-- <property-images v-if="getPropertyData" :propImages="getPropertyData.propertyData.property_detail.photos"/>
      <property-images v-if="getPropertyData" :propImages="getPropertyData.propertyData.property_detail.photos"/> -->
    </div>
    <div id="detailsContainer">
      <div id="detailsContent" v-if="getPropertyData">
        <span class="detailItem" v-for="dataPoint, key  in getPropertyData.propertyData.property_detail.prop_common">{{
          `${key}: ${dataPoint}` }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>





  </div>
</template>
<script>
// var map;
import VueGoogleAutocomplete from "vue-google-autocomplete";
import propertyImages from '@/components/propertyImages.vue'

import axios from "axios";
import { mapActions, mapGetters, mapMutations } from "vuex";
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";
const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyB2blQxoDxnSYS2AB80m1k8nfLjeS0jtnU",
  version: "weekly",
  // ...additionalOptions,
});
export default {
  components: {
    VueGoogleAutocomplete,
    propertyImages
  },
  data() {
    return {
      street: "",
      zip: "",
      dataAPI: false,
      loading: false,
      qualifies: "-",
      isDisabled: true,
      address: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getPropertyData',
      'getAddressToSearch'
    ])
  },
  watch: {
    'errors.items'() {

      if (this.$validator.errors.items.length == 0) {
        this.isDisabled = false
      }
      else {
        this.isDisabled = true
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'getRealestateDataFromAddress'
    ]),
    getRealestateData() {
      console.log(this.address)
      console.log(this.getAddressToSearch)
      this.getRealestateDataFromAddress()
     

        loader.load().then(() => {
              var myLatLng = { lat: Number(this.getAddressToSearch.latitude), lng: Number(this.getAddressToSearch.longitude) };
              const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: { lat: Number(this.getAddressToSearch.latitude), lng: Number(this.getAddressToSearch.longitude) },
                zoomControl: false, 
                mapTypeControl: false,
                zoom: 10,
              });
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
              });
            });
    
    },
    ...mapMutations([
      'setAddressToSearch'
    ]),
    getAddressData: function (addressData, placeResultData, id) {
      this.address = addressData
      this.setAddressToSearch(addressData);
     
    },

    submit() {

    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$validator.validate();
    console.log()
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: Google Maps already loaded outside @googlemaps/js-api-loader.This may result in undesirable behavior as options and script parameters may not match.

Comment: I have tried to address this, by removing the duplicate instance, however, it does not remedy the issue.

Comment: I had the brilliant idea to name the search box "map" as well, solved my own problem.